# How can I get open/save dialog to work on Electron v19?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, electron, dialog

I am quite new to Electron and am trying to make a note app where you can save and open note files. I am trying to set up a page where you can open a file. I have been following a few tutorials, but none of them seem to be working. I try:

```
const { dialog, app } = require('electron')

dialog.showOpenDialogSync(mainWindow, {
  properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory']
})
```

and my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

but I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialogSync')
    at app.js:3:8
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may need to show a little more code, such as what you have in your `main.js` file to create your window. You will want to use a `preload.js` script as well for security in your window creation. Finally, you will probably want a button in your `.html` file and some JS to send an IPC message to the main process to open up your file / directory dialog. Depending on your requirements, you may want your main process to reply to your render process with the path for display in a (form) field.